# Download File does not work on Chrome (Blazor)

Tags: google-chrome, blazor

I am building a web app in Blazor and have run into problems with downloading files. Everything works as expected when testing locally on Chrome or Edge. When it is published to the live site, I cannot download the same files on Chrome, although it still works on Edge.

Since it only fails on the live site, I have not been able to debug and determine the exact point of failure or the exception being thrown.

DownloadFile.Razor

```
<button @onclick="OnDownload">Download</button>

@code{
    [Parameter] public Func<Task<(string, string)>>? GenerateData {get; set;} = null;

    async Task OnDownload()
    {
        (string file_name, string data) = await GenerateData();
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data ?? ""), false);
        await DownloadFileFromStream(stream, file_name);
    {

    async Task DownloadFileFromStream(Stream fileStream, string fileName)
    {
        using var streamRef = new  DotNetStreamReference(stream: fileStream);
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFileFromStream", filename, streamRef);
    }
}
```

Reports.razor

```
<DownloadFile GenerateData="@GenerateReport></DownloadFile>

@code{
    async Task<(string, string)> GenerateReport()
    {
        string report = await Report.GetCSV();
        return ("Report.csv", report);
    }
}
```

Report.GetCSV() uses StringWriter and CsvWriter to return a string in CSV format containing all the data for the downloadable report.

Insight into why it only works locally or on Edge, or potential solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is `GenerateReport` `async Task` but nothing is awaited inside ? When going from local to live you are adding network delay. I'd bet you should `await Report.GetCSV()`.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine, thanks for the info. That was simply bad code copying on my part, the call to Report.GetCSV() is awaited. There are many <DownloadFile> components on the reports page to download a number of files. I am generating these reports in async methods so they can be downloaded asynchronously.

Comment: Enable development mode on your website, if any exception is thrown on your circuit you should have some information in the browser console.